# Advantages of SSD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

What are the advantages of a SSD drive in my laptop if they have not that a great lifespan and are quite expensive in first place?

Comment: They don't have a great lifespan? Compared to what?

Comment: You might find the recent SSD posts ([1](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/07/the-king-of-drives/), [2](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/25/the-king-of-kings-ssd-testing-part-2/) and [3](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/31/kingston-ssdnow-v100-official-review/)) on the new Super User blog helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I get a Solid State Drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/2347/should-i-get-a-solid-state-drive) - if not a duplicate question, the answers are on-topic to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Increased speed (especially when loading lots of small files on demand), higher mechanical durability/reliability and reduced power consumption are probably the biggest.

Wikipedia has a great article that further explains the benefits versus the disadvantages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive (about half way down)

Answer (score 0):

SSD drives are extremely fast compared to normal drives they have no moving parts so they are not susceptible to the mechanical issues normal drives have.

This makes them great for laptops as they are slower to begin with and need any edge they can get and because they have no moving parts they are less likely to break if you drop the laptop.

Comment: what do you mean by "laptops as they are slower to begin with"?

Comment: slower compared to desktops was speaking in a general sense... not all desktops are faster than all laptops obviously

Comment: Yeah, a $1000 laptop is probably about half or less of the performance of a $1000 desktop was the point.

Answer (score 0):

Pros

1. The speed, SSDs are faster because they use flash memory.
2. Reliability, SSDs have no moving parts so they are tougher.

Cons

1.Expensive

2. Last less than hard drives